# How to boot after RAID failure (software RAID)?

Tags: grub, mdadm

Previously I had a software raid set up using (`mdadm`) of drives `sda` and `sdb`. `sdb` failed and the only way to reboot the system was by unplugging the second hard drive.

Now I've added fresh `sdb` and `sdc` to my RAID setup. `sda` is the oldest (so most likely to fail) and it is the drive from which we boot (I think, how can I check?).

How can I ensure and test (through GRUB configuration, etc.) that if `sda` fails, I will still be able to boot my machine.

`fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 250.0 GB, 250000000000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 30394 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000080

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1       30064   241489048+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
/dev/sda2           30065       30394     2650725    5  Extended
/dev/sda5           30065       30394     2650693+  fd  Linux raid autodetect

Disk /dev/sdb: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *           1       30064   241489048+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdb2           30065       30394     2650725    5  Extended
/dev/sdb5           30065       30394     2650693+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/sdc: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdc1   *           1       30064   241489048+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 1 does not start on physical sector boundary.
/dev/sdc2           30065       30394     2650725    5  Extended
/dev/sdc5           30065       30394     2650693+  fd  Linux raid autodetect
Partition 5 does not start on physical sector boundary.

Disk /dev/md0: 247.3 GB, 247284695040 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 60372240 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md0 doesn't contain a valid partition table

Disk /dev/md1: 2714 MB, 2714238976 bytes
2 heads, 4 sectors/track, 662656 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 8 * 512 = 4096 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Alignment offset: 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Disk /dev/md1 doesn't contain a valid partition table
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not. Only unplugging sda will help in this case. In that case sdb will be sda... (braindead Linux device numbering - Solaris and HP-Unix use SCSI-IDs.)

So for the bootloader you should install it on sda and then copy it with `dd` to sdb and sdc.

Comment: So then as long as GRUB is set to boot from `md0` and a bootloader is found on `sdb`, my system should boot? 

When I installed the two fresh drives, I copied the partition table and put both partitions in the appropriate arrays `md0` and `md1` (as per [link](http://www.howtoforge.com/replacing_hard_disks_in_a_raid1_array)).

Are you saying I will still have to copy the bootloader manually on `sdb` and `sdc`? Is The bootloader not copied as a result of my RAID 1 setup? How can I check if it is? (Note: I'm not too familiar with bootloaders so I appreciate any advice)

Comment: Forgive my ignorance, but I ran `grub-install /dev/sdb` and I am wondering if that's sufficient to install the bootloader.

Comment: Note to any future readers, my RAID array disappeared after running `grub-install` as above so I'd recommend looking a bit more carefully...

Comment: @user1850672 Are you sure your grub has an idea what md0 is? I doubt this, since that code resides in the kernel or the initrd - which comes AFTER grub. The UUID of your boot-md-device is normally passed as kernel-parameter.

Comment: When I boot and select my kernel, the conf file is set to `md0` and when I run it as such it says `md0 does not exist`. I can only boot directly from `sda1` now. If you are more interested, I've recently asked other questions which give better characterizations of the problem. The consensus seems to be that my `md0` is gone but it is still strangely showing up in `mtab`

Comment: @user1850672 I think this is pretty normal. md0 starts up after the initrd has been loaded and processed. So grub can not see md0, but the fully loaded system does. I`ve never seen this in any other way (SLES 9/10, RedHat ES 3/4/5).